# access variables in layout partial from other controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, variables, partial-views, view-helpers

today I wanted to use some variables in my `shared/menu` partial. I know that I should put somewhere in `application_controller` some helper method (or something like that) but it doesn't work for me. Here is my temporary solution (`shared/_menu.html.haml`):

```
- @pagecontents = Pagecontent.all
- @pagecontents.each do |pc|
  %ul
    %li
      = link_to pc.title, pc
```

I don't want to define `@pagecontents` variable directly in my view! :/ My problem is to add `@pagecontent` variable somewhere to `application_controller` file but when I tried e.g:

```
def pagecontentforpartial
  @pagecontents = Pagecontent.all
end
```

and then tried to access this variable in my partial view I got an error that this method is `nil` (but there is already a lot of records!) Someone can explain me how solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass object to your partial directly using `render` method

It's your `shared/_menu.html.haml`:

```
- pagecontents.each do |pc|
%ul
  %li
    = link_to pc.title, pc
```

And when you need to show it, you can use this method in your view

```
render 'shared/menu', pagecontents: @pagecontents
```

`@pagecontents` is from controller, of course